# Recommended Implementation For Fields From Another System With Non-.Net Data Types

Tags: c#, .net

I am reading data from another system that returns XML that provides the following information for each field:
"Field Name", "Data Type", and "Size". The "Data Type" returned is either: Alpha, LAlpha, RAlpha, CAlpha, or Numeric. Sometimes there are other attributes returned as well, such as Casing. I would like to create objects to model the data returned and also have to generate xml with element values formatted according to the given data type to send back to the other system to perform transactions. I started off creating an object that would represent each property on the object like:

```
//Type T represents the data type of the Value property
public class OtherSystemField<T> : IOtherSystemField{ 

public string OtherSystemFieldName { get; set;}
public OtherSystemDataTypeEnum OtherSystemDataType { get; set;}
public int Size { get; set;}
public T Value { get; set;}
public string ToOtherSystemString() { ....};

}

//Class using the data field
public OtherSystemEntityClass {

public OtherSystemField<string> f1 { get; set; }
public OtherSystemEntityClass () {
f1 = new OtherSystemField<string>() { 
OtherSystemFieldName = "x", Size = 4, OtherSystemDataType = ...};
f1.Value = "DefaultStringValue"; 
}
}
```

The question is does this representation of the other system's data fields make the most sense, using this type of object to model a field from the other system instead of a .Net data type property that is associated with some meta-data?. Any opinions on, say, having the property have attributes containing these values like:

```
public OtherSystemEntityClass {

[OtherSystemFieldName("SomeFieldName", 5, OtherSystemDataTypeEnum.RAlpha)]
public string f1 { get; set; }

}
```

Here is an example of the XML:

```
<COLUMNS>  
<COLUMN header="FieldX" dspname="FieldX" dbname="FIELDX" type="NUMERIC" size="4" /> 
<COLUMN header="FieldY" dspname="FieldY" dbname="FIELDY" type="ALPHARIGHT" size="14"/>        
</COLUMNS> <COLS> <COL><![CDATA[ 1000]]></COL> <COL><![CDATA[ 102]]></COL> </COLS>
```

I look forward to everyone's feedback - I have no doubts I will hear good perspectives.
Performance is not of a huge concern, as the number of fields is relatively small. Also, this is implemented in .Net 3.5

Comment: Can you post an example of the XML?  I started writing an answer but I'm not completely sure if I understand the spec.

Comment: Wow, that XML is scary, glad I didn't post my answer because it would have been way off.  You should add this information to the question instead of posting it in a comment, it will be a lot easier to read.

Comment: @Aaronaught - thanks, forgive the noob mistake - I posted the XML in the question instead of the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the "Alpha" types are, but the newly-added XML snippet is clearly describing a table schema.  If you can pull off a mapping, I might actually use a `DataTable` instead of creating any custom classes at all.

I wouldn't be too surprised to find out that the XML is literally serialized directly from something similar to a .NET `DataSet`/`DataTable` but in a different language/platform.  Those CDATA tags are not consumer-friendly.  But if you can map `Alpha` values to some enum type (most likely a custom one you create), then you can just add a column of that type to a `DataTable`.

Comment: @Aaronaught - thanks for the feedback - I will definitely consider that route. You guess about the source of the XML is correct - and that language/platform would be Cobalt/AS400. The main reason I was leaning towards creating objects is each transaction interface I must feed will have quite a few of these objects passed to them - after they are passed the receiver will be writing back the required XML format.

Comment: @thedugas: You're using a few terms there that I'm not sure I'm familiar with ("transaction interface"), but if you have to manage a large amount of data then I think that `DataTable`/`DataSet` would definitely be the way to go.  But mainly I would choose it over concerns of having to change the class definitions every time the XML changes, whereas with a `DataTable` you construct the schema on the fly.  HTH!

Comment: I will try that route. As for the term "transaction interface" (I should have used better wording) - I meant that I have to construct XML to post back to the Application Gateway Server. Along with some other tags, if using a datatable, I have to write out XML elements like <FieldName>Value</FieldName> from the datatables. Thanks again for the feedback - the answer is yours.

Answer (score 1):

Do you already know the Field Name, Data Type, Size, etc of your fields or is this something that you need to determine at run time? If you already know all the information about the fields at design time, then I like the attribute approach. I've done the very same when dealing with incoming Xml from old systems. You can then [deserialize](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization) the Xml to your objects, and you're good to go.

If you do not know the format of the Xml at design time, that is, you need to set the attribute values at run time, then using attributes will be more difficult than your first approach. You would need to set the attributes with reflection, which would be more work than just setting a property in the first solution.

Comment: @wsanville - Everything is known at compile time.